# how to add a wms layer to a bing map using javascript?

Tags: javascript, bing-maps, openlayers, proj4js, wms

how do I add a wms layer to a bing map using javascript? anyone know any good examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically I've used a proxy service that translates the quad key to the proper coordinates of the wms.  A good start for writing such a proxy service in C# as a web handler can be found here: http://www.viawindowslive.com/Articles/VirtualEarth/AccessingWMSfromVirtualEarth.aspx

The problem lies in the way that bings maps requires you to specify a tile url. If you're not locked into bing maps, this sort of thing is much easier with Google Maps version 2.0 or Open layers as the above poster suggested.

Answer (score 0):

if you have to use WMS for the tile server, then I would seriously look at [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org).
This is excellent at mixing different toolkits and formats. Eg. putting KML overlays over WMS, or (as in your case) WMS over Bing Maps.

If you have your own choice of tile server and you have rasters, then I would use MapCruncher instead and load it natively in Bing Maps.

Comment: And add Proj4JS (used by OpenLayers) to perform any re-projections that are necessary.